# NTLM authentication in React-Native with 'httpntlm'

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, browserify, ntlm

I am making a `react-native` app that gets some data from backend which has `ntlm authentication` system. I tried using package 'httpntlm' but it didn't work with react-native. As it is core node library, it worked with `node js` but not with react-native. What should I do to be able to use it with react-native? Please suggest steps that I should follow.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach is to use fetch() and implement the NTLM handshake *yourself*. Have a look at the [advanced section of the library](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm#advanced).

NTLM consists of 3 messages:

- message type 1 is sent to the server
- message type 2 is a reply from the server
- message type 3 is sent to the server

Using [React Native's fetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network), sending message type 1 could be something like this:

```
var options = {
    url: "https://someurl.com",
    username: 'm$',
    password: 'stinks',
    workstation: 'choose.something',
    domain: ''
};

var type1msg = ntlm.createType1Message(options);

fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Authorization': type1msg
  }
});
```

Good luck

Comment: Can you elaborate on the line: var type1msg = ntlm.createType1Message(options);
Where to find ntlm.createType1Message() function.